# second argument as function or object in javascript and append to the empty object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arguments

I have created a function to us for  namespace but how to extend its functionality

code:

```
MY.property = function (str, obj, prevent) {

    var ns = obj || MY,
            k = str.split(".");
    while (k.length > 1) {
        if (!prevent && typeof ns[k[0]] === "undefined") {
            ns[k[0]] = {};
        }
        if (ns[k[0]]) {
            ns = ns[k.shift()];
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    return [ns, [k[0]]];
};


MY.namespace = function (str) {
    var ns = this.property(str),
    k = str.split(".");
    if (k[0] === "MY") {
        k.shift();
    }
    if (ns && ns[0][ns[1]]) {
        return;
    } else {
        ns[0][ns[1]] = {};
    }
    return true;
};
```

This only works for MY.namespace("test") , var My.test = function(){}; but how can I extend it like this MY.namespace("test", function(){ }); and MY.namespace("test", {});

Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 1):

[**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qk6Kj/)

The special operator [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof)  should be enough to accomplish this:

```
My.namespace = function (str, obj) {

     if (obj) {
          this[str] = obj;
     }
     ....

My.namespace('test', function () {console.log('here');});
My.test()
```

EDIT: An updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/qk6Kj/1/

Comment: Why the first obj in `if (obj || typeof obj === "function")`?  Won't `if (obj)` do the same?  Or, should this be just `if (typeof obj === "function")` to ensure that obj is a function?

Comment: @jfriend, you are right. I combined an if else statement without really thinking it through.

Comment: @joey instead of passing a another argument if I can use typeof argument[1] === "Object" || typeof argument[1] === "function since I want to pass second argument as object or function

Comment: @joey this will fail when u r passing a immediate function like MY.namespace("immediate", (function(){...}());